# Debugging interactive console application in Python with Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

What console do I have to use if I want to debug an console application, that expect user input to continue? I tried both, the "python console" and the "Console for currently active editors". 
Also the standard console that opens normaly shows me the prompt, that I have to give input. But if I'm writing a command and hitting enter in this console, it just prints my command out with "^J" at the end. Thank you for your answer!

Current System:

- Python 2.7
- PyDev 3.9.2....
- Eclipse 3.8.1
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Are you searching for `pdb`? It's the Python DeBugger. Allows you to put stop points, execute code step by step, launch some python between steps...

Comment: No I'm searching for a way to give my application the input it needs, for example a word for a hungman game, when I let it run inside pydev in eclipse.

Comment: @Pumba did you get a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem.